# Is LSM303dlhc INT1 active HI and DRDY active LO?

Tags: accelerometer, magnetometer

I just want to make sure I am approaching my [LSM303DLHC](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00027543.pdf) design properly, and 
that I'm correct in the active state of the two pins.

I setup the following registers as indicated:

```
CTRL_REG1_A:  77    
CTRL_REG2_A:  00                                           
CTRL_REG3_A:  10 
CTRL_REG4_A:  88                                           
CTRL_REG5_A:  00    
CTRL_REG6_A:  00   (ooops - had forgot this one)

CRA_REG_M:    1C    
CRB_REG_M:    80                                             
MR_REG_M:     00
INT1_CFG_A:   00 
INT2_CFG_A:   00                                           
CLICK_CFG_A:  00
```

I then use the INT1 PIN as an accelerometer data ready flag, where it is active HI (1 = new data available).

I then read all 6 Acc data registers (OUT_X_L_A - OUT_Z_H_A, bytes B0 - B5) sequentially, and end up with values ...

```
   B1 B0    B3 B2    B5 B4 
   XX X0    YY Y0    ZZ Z0
```

I use the DRDY PIN as a magnetometer data ready flag, where it is active LO (0 = new data available).

I then read all 6 Mag data registers (OUT_X_H_M - OUT_Y_L_M, bytes B0 - B5) sequentially, and end up with values ...

```
   B0 B1    B2 B3    B4 B5 
   0X XX    0Z ZZ    0Y YY
```

Are the Z/Y registers for Mag data really oriented differently then the Acc data ?

Comment: Yes, the registers are that way around. See table 17 on page 23 of the datasheet. It tells you the register map

Answer (score 1):

The registers are indeed that way around. In the datasheet (link in question), if you have a look at **Table 17**, which is on **page 23**, you will find a full register map, and the ordering of the registers.

For the Accelerometer:

[image: Accelerometer out]

For the Magnetometer

[image: Magnetometer out]

As you can see, the ordering is indeed different for each of the two sensors.

Comment: I assume due to CTRL_REG6_A = 00h, that my use of ACC INT1 pin as active high flag is correct ... but not totally sure of the MAG DRDY pin.